No network (both LAN and internet) after updating my Ubuntu
My server has on about 20 days straight without any problems with networking, but after updating my Ubuntu and rebooting I don't have any more network (both LAN and internet).


Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

The service NetworkManager doesn't exist when i use the command.

Plus when i use the command service --status-all doesn't show networking.

You say this is a server, but your image shows a Gnome desktop. So is this Ubuntu Server (which uses networkd) or is this Ubuntu Desktop (which uses NetworkManager)? Also, review your logs -- this kind of troubleshooting is exactly why you have them. It's unclear what "Both Internet LAN" means. Please edit your question to clarify all these. Also, while editing, please clearly explain what network connection you expect to see.

This server uses Ubuntu with GUI (not ubuntu server), like i said in my first comment, i am new to this kind of stuff in linux. Don't how to review my logs, that is why i am trying to get help.
